# Rails, destroy versus delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why does this work:

```
@poll_votes = PollVote.where(:user_id => self.user_id, :poll_id => self.poll_id).all

@poll_votes.each do |p|
  p.destroy
end
```

But this does not?

```
@poll_votes = PollVote.where(:user_id => self.user_id, :poll_id => self.poll_id).destroy
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work: 
PollVote.destroy_all(:user_id => self.user_id, :poll_id => self.poll_id)

Answer (score 15):

The where method returns an enumerable collection of activerecord objects meeting the selection criteria. Calling the destroy method on that collection is different than calling the destroy method on a single activerecord object.

Comment: @AnApprentice, you didn't asked for solution, you asked why something doesn't work, and Fred gave you good explanation, so his answer could be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

'where' is a named scope. You are calling a destroy method on a named-scope collection. Try destroy_all